# %%writetemplate doesn't work after elif statement

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

I'd like to change the original file (`common.py`):

```
%cat /content/yolov5/models/common.py

import math

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

from utils.datasets import letterbox
from utils.general import non_max_suppression, make_divisible, scale_coords, xyxy2xywh
from utils.plots import color_list


def autopad(k, p=None):  # kernel, padding
    # Pad to 'same'
    if p is None:
        p = k // 2 if isinstance(k, int) else [x // 2 for x in k]  # auto-pad
    return p
```

To:

```
%%writetemplate /content/yolov5/models/common.py

# This file contains modules common to various models

import json
import math
import platform
import warnings
from collections import OrderedDict, namedtuple
from copy import copy
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn.modules.utils import _triple, _pair, _single
from PIL import Image
from torch.cuda import amp

from utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox
from utils.general import (LOGGER, ROOT, Profile, check_requirements, check_suffix, check_version, colorstr,
                           increment_path, make_divisible, non_max_suppression, scale_boxes, xywh2xyxy, xyxy2xywh,
                           yaml_load)
from utils.plots import Annotator, colors, save_one_box
from utils.torch_utils import copy_attr, smart_inference_mode


def autopad(k, p=None, d=1):  # kernel, padding, dilation
    # Pad to 'same' shape outputs
    if d > 1:
        k = d * (k - 1) + 1 if isinstance(k, int) else [d * (x - 1) + 1 for x in k]  # actual kernel-size
    if p is None:
        p = k // 2 if isinstance(k, int) else [x // 2 for x in k]  # auto-pad
    return p


class Conv(nn.Module):
    # Standard convolution with args(ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, padding, groups, dilation, activation)
    default_act = nn.SiLU()  # default activation

    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=1, s=1, p=None, g=1, d=1, act=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(c1, c2, k, s, autopad(k, p, d), groups=g, dilation=d, bias=False)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(c2)
        self.act = self.default_act if act is True else act if isinstance(act, nn.Module) else nn.Identity()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.act(self.bn(self.conv(x)))

    def forward_fuse(self, x):
        return self.act(self.conv(x))


class DWConv(Conv):
    # Depth-wise convolution
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=1, s=1, d=1, act=True):  # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, dilation, activation
        super().__init__(c1, c2, k, s, g=math.gcd(c1, c2), d=d, act=act)


class DWConvTranspose2d(nn.ConvTranspose2d):
    # Depth-wise transpose convolution
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=1, s=1, p1=0, p2=0):  # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, padding, padding_out
        super().__init__(c1, c2, k, s, p1, p2, groups=math.gcd(c1, c2))


class TransformerLayer(nn.Module):
    # Transformer layer https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11929 (LayerNorm layers removed for better performance)
    def __init__(self, c, num_heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = nn.Linear(c, c, bias=False)
        self.k = nn.Linear(c, c, bias=False)
        self.v = nn.Linear(c, c, bias=False)
        self.ma = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim=c, num_heads=num_heads)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(c, c, bias=False)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(c, c, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.ma(self.q(x), self.k(x), self.v(x))[0] + x
        x = self.fc2(self.fc1(x)) + x
        return x


class TransformerBlock(nn.Module):
    # Vision Transformer https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11929
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, num_heads, num_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = None
        if c1 != c2:
            self.conv = Conv(c1, c2)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(c2, c2)  # learnable position embedding
        self.tr = nn.Sequential(*(TransformerLayer(c2, num_heads) for _ in range(num_layers)))
        self.c2 = c2

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.conv is not None:
            x = self.conv(x)
        b, _, w, h = x.shape
        p = x.flatten(2).permute(2, 0, 1)
        return self.tr(p + self.linear(p)).permute(1, 2, 0).reshape(b, self.c2, w, h)


class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    # Standard bottleneck
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5):  # ch_in, ch_out, shortcut, groups, expansion
        super().__init__()
        c_ = int(c2 * e)  # hidden channels
        self.cv1 = Conv(c1, c_, 1, 1)
        self.cv2 = Conv(c_, c2, 3, 1, g=g)
        self.add = shortcut and c1 == c2

    def forward(self, x):
        return x + self.cv2(self.cv1(x)) if self.add else self.cv2(self.cv1(x))


class BottleneckCSP(nn.Module):
    # CSP Bottleneck https://github.com/WongKinYiu/CrossStagePartialNetworks
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, n=1, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5):  # ch_in, ch_out, number, shortcut, groups, expansion
        super().__init__()
        c_ = int(c2 * e)  # hidden channels
        self.cv1 = Conv(c1, c_, 1, 1)
        self.cv2 = nn.Conv2d(c1, c_, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.cv3 = nn.Conv2d(c_, c_, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.cv4 = Conv(2 * c_, c2, 1, 1)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(2 * c_)  # applied to cat(cv2, cv3)
        self.act = nn.SiLU()
        self.m = nn.Sequential(*(Bottleneck(c_, c_, shortcut, g, e=1.0) for _ in range(n)))

    def forward(self, x):
        y1 = self.cv3(self.m(self.cv1(x)))
        y2 = self.cv2(x)
        return self.cv4(self.act(self.bn(torch.cat((y1, y2), 1))))


class CrossConv(nn.Module):
    # Cross Convolution Downsample
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=3, s=1, g=1, e=1.0, shortcut=False):
        # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, groups, expansion, shortcut
        super().__init__()
        c_ = int(c2 * e)  # hidden channels
        self.cv1 = Conv(c1, c_, (1, k), (1, s))
        self.cv2 = Conv(c_, c2, (k, 1), (s, 1), g=g)
        self.add = shortcut and c1 == c2

    def forward(self, x):
        return x + self.cv2(self.cv1(x)) if self.add else self.cv2(self.cv1(x))


class C3(nn.Module):
    # CSP Bottleneck with 3 convolutions
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, n=1, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5):  # ch_in, ch_out, number, shortcut, groups, expansion
        super().__init__()
        c_ = int(c2 * e)  # hidden channels
        self.cv1 = Conv(c1, c_, 1, 1)
        self.cv2 = Conv(c1, c_, 1, 1)
        self.cv3 = Conv(2 * c_, c2, 1)  # optional act=FReLU(c2)
        self.m = nn.Sequential(*(Bottleneck(c_, c_, shortcut, g, e=1.0) for _ in range(n)))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.cv3(torch.cat((self.m(self.cv1(x)), self.cv2(x)), 1))


class C3x(C3):
    # C3 module with cross-convolutions
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, n=1, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5):
        super().__init__(c1, c2, n, shortcut, g, e)
        c_ = int(c2 * e)
        self.m = nn.Sequential(*(CrossConv(c_, c_, 3, 1, g, 1.0, shortcut) for _ in range(n)))


class C3TR(C3):
    # C3 module with TransformerBlock()
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, n=1, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5):
        super().__init__(c1, c2, n, shortcut, g, e)
        c_ = int(c2 * e)
        self.m = TransformerBlock(c_, c_, 4, n)


class C3SPP(C3):
    # C3 module with SPP()
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=(5, 9, 13), n=1, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5):
        super().__init__(c1, c2, n, shortcut, g, e)
        c_ = int(c2 * e)
        self.m = SPP(c_, c_, k)


class C3Ghost(C3):
    # C3 module with GhostBottleneck()
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, n=1, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5):
        super().__init__(c1, c2, n, shortcut, g, e)
        c_ = int(c2 * e)  # hidden channels
        self.m = nn.Sequential(*(GhostBottleneck(c_, c_) for _ in range(n)))


class SPP(nn.Module):
    # Spatial Pyramid Pooling (SPP) layer https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=(5, 9, 13)):
        super().__init__()
        c_ = c1 // 2  # hidden channels
        self.cv1 = Conv(c1, c_, 1, 1)
        self.cv2 = Conv(c_ * (len(k) + 1), c2, 1, 1)
        self.m = nn.ModuleList([nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=x, stride=1, padding=x // 2) for x in k])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cv1(x)
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore')  # suppress torch 1.9.0 max_pool2d() warning
            return self.cv2(torch.cat([x] + [m(x) for m in self.m], 1))


class SoftPool2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, stride, padding=0):
        super(SoftPool2d, self).__init__()
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.stride = stride
        self.padding = padding

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.soft_pool2d(x, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, stride=self.stride)
        return x

    def soft_pool2d(self, x, kernel_size=2, stride=None):
        kernel_size = _pair(kernel_size)
        stride = kernel_size if stride is None else _pair(stride)
        e_x = torch.sum(torch.exp(x), dim=1, keepdim=True)
        return F.avg_pool2d(x.mul(e_x), kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=self.padding).mul_(sum(kernel_size)).div_(
            F.avg_pool2d(e_x, kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=self.padding).mul_(sum(kernel_size)))


class Focus(nn.Module):
    # Focus wh information into c-space
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=1, s=1, p=None, g=1, act=True):  # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, padding, groups
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = Conv(c1 * 4, c2, k, s, p, g, act=act)
        # self.contract = Contract(gain=2)

    def forward(self, x):  # x(b,c,w,h) -> y(b,4c,w/2,h/2)
        return self.conv(torch.cat((x[..., ::2, ::2], x[..., 1::2, ::2], x[..., ::2, 1::2], x[..., 1::2, 1::2]), 1))
        # return self.conv(self.contract(x))


class GhostConv(nn.Module):
    # Ghost Convolution https://github.com/huawei-noah/ghostnet
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=1, s=1, g=1, act=True):  # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, groups
        super().__init__()
        c_ = c2 // 2  # hidden channels
        self.cv1 = Conv(c1, c_, k, s, None, g, act=act)
        self.cv2 = Conv(c_, c_, 5, 1, None, c_, act=act)

    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.cv1(x)
        return torch.cat((y, self.cv2(y)), 1)


class GhostBottleneck(nn.Module):
    # Ghost Bottleneck https://github.com/huawei-noah/ghostnet
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=3, s=1):  # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride
        super().__init__()
        c_ = c2 // 2
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            GhostConv(c1, c_, 1, 1),  # pw
            DWConv(c_, c_, k, s, act=False) if s == 2 else nn.Identity(),  # dw
            GhostConv(c_, c2, 1, 1, act=False))  # pw-linear
        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(DWConv(c1, c1, k, s, act=False), Conv(c1, c2, 1, 1,
                                                                            act=False)) if s == 2 else nn.Identity()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x) + self.shortcut(x)


class Contract(nn.Module):
    # Contract width-height into channels, i.e. x(1,64,80,80) to x(1,256,40,40)
    def __init__(self, gain=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.gain = gain

    def forward(self, x):
        b, c, h, w = x.size()  # assert (h / s == 0) and (W / s == 0), 'Indivisible gain'
        s = self.gain
        x = x.view(b, c, h // s, s, w // s, s)  # x(1,64,40,2,40,2)
        x = x.permute(0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4).contiguous()  # x(1,2,2,64,40,40)
        return x.view(b, c * s * s, h // s, w // s)  # x(1,256,40,40)


class Expand(nn.Module):
    # Expand channels into width-height, i.e. x(1,64,80,80) to x(1,16,160,160)
    def __init__(self, gain=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.gain = gain

    def forward(self, x):
        b, c, h, w = x.size()  # assert C / s ** 2 == 0, 'Indivisible gain'
        s = self.gain
        x = x.view(b, s, s, c // s ** 2, h, w)  # x(1,2,2,16,80,80)
        x = x.permute(0, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2).contiguous()  # x(1,16,80,2,80,2)
        return x.view(b, c // s ** 2, h * s, w * s)  # x(1,16,160,160)


class Concat(nn.Module):
    # Concatenate a list of tensors along dimension
    def __init__(self, dimension=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.d = dimension

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.cat(x, self.d)


class DetectMultiBackend(nn.Module):
    # YOLOv5 MultiBackend class for python inference on various backends
    def __init__(self, weights='yolov5s.pt', device=torch.device('cpu'), dnn=False, data=None, fp16=False, fuse=True):
        # Usage:
        #   PyTorch:              weights = *.pt
        #   TorchScript:                    *.torchscript
        #   ONNX Runtime:                   *.onnx
        #   ONNX OpenCV DNN:                *.onnx --dnn
        #   OpenVINO:                       *.xml
        #   CoreML:                         *.mlmodel
        #   TensorRT:                       *.engine
        #   TensorFlow SavedModel:          *_saved_model
        #   TensorFlow GraphDef:            *.pb
        #   TensorFlow Lite:                *.tflite
        #   TensorFlow Edge TPU:            *_edgetpu.tflite
        #   PaddlePaddle:                   *_paddle_model
        from models.experimental import attempt_download, attempt_load  # scoped to avoid circular import

        super().__init__()
        w = str(weights[0] if isinstance(weights, list) else weights)
        pt, jit, onnx, xml, engine, coreml, saved_model, pb, tflite, edgetpu, tfjs, paddle, triton = self._model_type(w)
        fp16 &= pt or jit or onnx or engine  # FP16
        nhwc = coreml or saved_model or pb or tflite or edgetpu  # BHWC formats (vs torch BCWH)
        stride = 32  # default stride
        cuda = torch.cuda.is_available() and device.type != 'cpu'  # use CUDA
        if not (pt or triton):
            w = attempt_download(w)  # download if not local

        if pt:  # PyTorch
            model = attempt_load(weights if isinstance(weights, list) else w, device=device, inplace=True, fuse=fuse)
            stride = max(int(model.stride.max()), 32)  # model stride
            names = model.module.names if hasattr(model, 'module') else model.names  # get class names
            model.half() if fp16 else model.float()
            self.model = model  # explicitly assign for to(), cpu(), cuda(), half()
        elif jit:  # TorchScript
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for TorchScript inference...')
            extra_files = {'config.txt': ''}  # model metadata
            model = torch.jit.load(w, _extra_files=extra_files, map_location=device)
            model.half() if fp16 else model.float()
            if extra_files['config.txt']:  # load metadata dict
                d = json.loads(extra_files['config.txt'],
                               object_hook=lambda d: {int(k) if k.isdigit() else k: v
                                                      for k, v in d.items()})
                stride, names = int(d['stride']), d['names']
        elif dnn:  # ONNX OpenCV DNN
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for ONNX OpenCV DNN inference...')
            check_requirements('opencv-python>=4.5.4')
            net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(w)
        elif onnx:  # ONNX Runtime
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for ONNX Runtime inference...')
            check_requirements(('onnx', 'onnxruntime-gpu' if cuda else 'onnxruntime'))
            import onnxruntime
            providers = ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'] if cuda else ['CPUExecutionProvider']
            session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(w, providers=providers)
            output_names = [x.name for x in session.get_outputs()]
            meta = session.get_modelmeta().custom_metadata_map  # metadata
            if 'stride' in meta:
                stride, names = int(meta['stride']), eval(meta['names'])
        elif xml:  # OpenVINO
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for OpenVINO inference...')
            check_requirements('openvino')  # requires openvino-dev: https://pypi.org/project/openvino-dev/
            from openvino.runtime import Core, Layout, get_batch
            ie = Core()
            if not Path(w).is_file():  # if not *.xml
                w = next(Path(w).glob('*.xml'))  # get *.xml file from *_openvino_model dir
            network = ie.read_model(model=w, weights=Path(w).with_suffix('.bin'))
            if network.get_parameters()[0].get_layout().empty:
                network.get_parameters()[0].set_layout(Layout("NCHW"))
            batch_dim = get_batch(network)
            if batch_dim.is_static:
                batch_size = batch_dim.get_length()
            executable_network = ie.compile_model(network, device_name="CPU")  # device_name="MYRIAD" for Intel NCS2
            stride, names = self._load_metadata(Path(w).with_suffix('.yaml'))  # load metadata
        elif engine:  # TensorRT
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for TensorRT inference...')
            import tensorrt as trt  # https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-tensorrt-download
            check_version(trt.__version__, '7.0.0', hard=True)  # require tensorrt>=7.0.0
            if device.type == 'cpu':
                device = torch.device('cuda:0')
            Binding = namedtuple('Binding', ('name', 'dtype', 'shape', 'data', 'ptr'))
            logger = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)
            with open(w, 'rb') as f, trt.Runtime(logger) as runtime:
                model = runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine(f.read())
            context = model.create_execution_context()
            bindings = OrderedDict()
            output_names = []
            fp16 = False  # default updated below
            dynamic = False
            for i in range(model.num_bindings):
                name = model.get_binding_name(i)
                dtype = trt.nptype(model.get_binding_dtype(i))
                if model.binding_is_input(i):
                    if -1 in tuple(model.get_binding_shape(i)):  # dynamic
                        dynamic = True
                        context.set_binding_shape(i, tuple(model.get_profile_shape(0, i)[2]))
                    if dtype == np.float16:
                        fp16 = True
                else:  # output
                    output_names.append(name)
                shape = tuple(context.get_binding_shape(i))
                im = torch.from_numpy(np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)).to(device)
                bindings[name] = Binding(name, dtype, shape, im, int(im.data_ptr()))
            binding_addrs = OrderedDict((n, d.ptr) for n, d in bindings.items())
            batch_size = bindings['images'].shape[0]  # if dynamic, this is instead max batch size
        elif coreml:  # CoreML
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for CoreML inference...')
            import coremltools as ct
            model = ct.models.MLModel(w)
        elif saved_model:  # TF SavedModel
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for TensorFlow SavedModel inference...')
            import tensorflow as tf
            keras = False  # assume TF1 saved_model
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model(w) if keras else tf.saved_model.load(w)
        elif pb:  # GraphDef https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_graphpb_or_graphpbtxt
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for TensorFlow GraphDef inference...')
            import tensorflow as tf

            def wrap_frozen_graph(gd, inputs, outputs):
                x = tf.compat.v1.wrap_function(lambda: tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(gd, name=""), [])  # wrapped
                ge = x.graph.as_graph_element
                return x.prune(tf.nest.map_structure(ge, inputs), tf.nest.map_structure(ge, outputs))

            def gd_outputs(gd):
                name_list, input_list = [], []
                for node in gd.node:  # tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2.NodeDef
                    name_list.append(node.name)
                    input_list.extend(node.input)
                return sorted(f'{x}:0' for x in list(set(name_list) - set(input_list)) if not x.startswith('NoOp'))

            gd = tf.Graph().as_graph_def()  # TF GraphDef
            with open(w, 'rb') as f:
                gd.ParseFromString(f.read())
            frozen_func = wrap_frozen_graph(gd, inputs="x:0", outputs=gd_outputs(gd))
        elif tflite or edgetpu:  # https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python#install_tensorflow_lite_for_python
            try:  # https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/tflite-python/#update-existing-tf-lite-code-for-the-edge-tpu
                from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter, load_delegate
            except ImportError:
                import tensorflow as tf
                Interpreter, load_delegate = tf.lite.Interpreter, tf.lite.experimental.load_delegate,
            if edgetpu:  # TF Edge TPU https://coral.ai/software/#edgetpu-runtime
                LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for TensorFlow Lite Edge TPU inference...')
                delegate = {
                    'Linux': 'libedgetpu.so.1',
                    'Darwin': 'libedgetpu.1.dylib',
                    'Windows': 'edgetpu.dll'}[platform.system()]
                interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=w, experimental_delegates=[load_delegate(delegate)])
            else:  # TFLite
                LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for TensorFlow Lite inference...')
                interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=w)  # load TFLite model
            interpreter.allocate_tensors()  # allocate
            input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()  # inputs
            output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()  # outputs
        elif tfjs:  # TF.js
            raise NotImplementedError('ERROR: YOLOv5 TF.js inference is not supported')
        elif paddle:  # PaddlePaddle
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for PaddlePaddle inference...')
            check_requirements('paddlepaddle-gpu' if cuda else 'paddlepaddle')
            import paddle.inference as pdi
            if not Path(w).is_file():  # if not *.pdmodel
                w = next(Path(w).rglob('*.pdmodel'))  # get *.xml file from *_openvino_model dir
            weights = Path(w).with_suffix('.pdiparams')
            config = pdi.Config(str(w), str(weights))
            if cuda:
                config.enable_use_gpu(memory_pool_init_size_mb=2048, device_id=0)
            predictor = pdi.create_predictor(config)
            input_handle = predictor.get_input_handle(predictor.get_input_names()[0])
            output_names = predictor.get_output_names()
        elif triton:  # NVIDIA Triton Inference Server
            LOGGER.info(f'Using {w} as Triton Inference Server...')
            check_requirements('tritonclient[all]')
            from utils.triton import TritonRemoteModel
            model = TritonRemoteModel(url=w)
            nhwc = model.runtime.startswith("tensorflow")
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f'ERROR: {w} is not a supported format')

        # class names
        if 'names' not in locals():
            names = yaml_load(data)['names'] if data else {i: f'class{i}' for i in range(999)}
        if names[0] == 'n01440764' and len(names) == 1000:  # ImageNet
            names = yaml_load(ROOT / 'data/ImageNet.yaml')['names']  # human-readable names

        self.__dict__.update(locals())  # assign all variables to self

    def forward(self, im, augment=False, visualize=False):
        # YOLOv5 MultiBackend inference
        b, ch, h, w = im.shape  # batch, channel, height, width
        if self.fp16 and im.dtype != torch.float16:
            im = im.half()  # to FP16
        if self.nhwc:
            im = im.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  # torch BCHW to numpy BHWC shape(1,320,192,3)

        if self.pt:  # PyTorch
            y = self.model(im, augment=augment, visualize=visualize) if augment or visualize else self.model(im)
        elif self.jit:  # TorchScript
            y = self.model(im)
        elif self.dnn:  # ONNX OpenCV DNN
            im = im.cpu().numpy()  # torch to numpy
            self.net.setInput(im)
            y = self.net.forward()
        elif self.onnx:  # ONNX Runtime
            im = im.cpu().numpy()  # torch to numpy
            y = self.session.run(self.output_names, {self.session.get_inputs()[0].name: im})
        elif self.xml:  # OpenVINO
            im = im.cpu().numpy()  # FP32
            y = list(self.executable_network([im]).values())
        elif self.engine:  # TensorRT
            if self.dynamic and im.shape != self.bindings['images'].shape:
                i = self.model.get_binding_index('images')
                self.context.set_binding_shape(i, im.shape)  # reshape if dynamic
                self.bindings['images'] = self.bindings['images']._replace(shape=im.shape)
                for name in self.output_names:
                    i = self.model.get_binding_index(name)


class Classify(nn.Module):
    # YOLOv5 classification head, i.e. x(b,c1,20,20) to x(b,c2)
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, k=1, s=1, p=None, g=1):  # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, padding, groups
        super().__init__()
        c_ = 1280  # efficientnet_b0 size
        self.conv = Conv(c1, c_, k, s, autopad(k, p), g)
        self.pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)  # to x(b,c_,1,1)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(c_, c2)  # to x(b,c2)

    def forward(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            x = torch.cat(x, 1)
        return self.linear(self.drop(self.pool(self.conv(x)).flatten(1)))
```

But the `writetemplate` always return:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-cb100cecc122> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('writetemplate', '/content/yolov5/models/common.py', '\n# This file contains modules common to various models\n\nimport json\nimport math\nimport platform\nimport warnings\nfrom collections import OrderedDict, namedtuple\nfrom copy import copy\nfrom pathlib import Path\nfrom urllib.parse import urlparse\n\nimport cv2\nimport numpy as np\nimport pandas as pd\nimport requests\nimport torch\nimport torch.nn as nn\nimport torch.nn.functional as F\nfrom torch.nn.modules.utils import _triple, _pair, _single\nfrom PIL import Image\nfrom torch.cuda import amp\n\nfrom utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox\nfrom utils.general import (LOGGER, ROOT, Profile, check_requirements, check_suffix, check_version, colorstr,\n                           increment_path, make_divisible, non_max_suppression, scale_boxes, xywh2xyxy, xyxy2xywh,\n                           yaml_load)\nfrom utils.plots import Annotator, colors, save_one_box\nfrom utils.torch_utils import copy_attr, smart_inference_mode\n\n\ndef autopad(k, p=None, d=1):  # kernel, padding, dilation\n    # Pad to \'same\' shape outputs\n    if d > 1:\n        k = d * (k - 1) + 1 if isinstance(k, int) else [d * (x - 1) + 1 for x in k]  # actual kernel-size\n    if p is None:\n        p = k // 2 if isinstance(k, int) else [x // 2 for x in k]  # auto-pad\n    return p...

1 frames
<ipython-input-7-fafe4f3ea491> in writetemplate(line, cell)
      5 def writetemplate(line, cell):
      6     with open(line, 'w') as f:
----> 7         f.write(cell.format(**globals()))

KeyError: 'w'
```

But the problem starts after the first `elfit` in:

```
        elif jit:  # TorchScript
            LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for TorchScript inference...')
            extra_files = {'config.txt': ''}  # model metadata
            model = torch.jit.load(w, _extra_files=extra_files, map_location=device)
            model.half() if fp16 else model.float()
            if extra_files['config.txt']:  # load metadata dict
                d = json.loads(extra_files['config.txt'],
                               object_hook=lambda d: {int(k) if k.isdigit() else k: v
                                                      for k, v in d.items()})
                stride, names = int(d['stride']), d['names']
```

Please, any help with it?

Comment: try to relace all single quotes with double quotes

Comment: Thanks, but not yet. If I change all single by double quotes: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-61ea2e4813cc> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('writetemplate', '/content/yolov5/models/common.py', '\n# This file contains modules common to various models\n\nimport json\nimport math\nimport ... KeyError: 'w'